# How can I debug native Android platform code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I'm interested in learning about the Android runtime (ART) and I'd like to be able to put a debugger on it so I can step through the code. I have an AOSP build that I've been running on an emulator.

What's the best way to attach and run source? Should I just use gdbserver on the emulator? Are there any IDEs that people use for native debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to debug native code, you're going to need the source, which of course means getting the AOSP. After you've setup the AOSP, do the following:

1. In your AOSP directory, run "choosecombo". Select "debug" and pick an "eng" build of your choice.
2. Build the AOSP
3. Start the emulator (ie: on Linux, "emulator &")
4. adb shell into the emulator and run "setprop debug.db.uid 32767". This prevents debuggerd from attaching to a process that it thinks has halted and causing problems. See system/core/debuggerd/debuggerd.cpp in the AOSP for more info.
5. In the same shell that you built the AOSP, run "gdbclient [process name]". This will attach and load the debugging information for the process you are interested in. You can also attach to a pid, but you will end up having to load the symbol information yourself.
6. Enjoy debugging native Android platform code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you figured this out, but just for completeness, here's a link to some official documentation which basically covers what you said: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/index.html